# XSL: Search for an element having an attribute equals to one property of the current attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've an XML which looks currently like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RootConfig>
  <RandomNode RefId="519263a7-e01e-4cc8-911e-7660dca717bf">
    <Id>101010101010</Id>
  </RandomNode>

  <Item Value="519263a7-e01e-4cc8-911e-7660dca717bf;bf139890-2f7c-4784-8041-68aa5fe7beb1" Type="SomeUniqueType" />
  <Item Value="519263a7-e01e-4cc8-911e-7660dca717bf;5fb8bea0-c79a-4a26-a532-4df59543bc5c" Type="SomeUniqueType" />
  <Item Value="519263a7-e01e-4cc8-911e-7660dca717bf;4f01116a-06f8-4af3-9f4a-87c658eb8008" Type="SomeUniqueType" />
</RootConfig>
```

In each item, the value is referencing another node, and giving for this given node a reference.

I've to change this to ends with a file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootConfig>
  <RandomNode RefId="519263a7-e01e-4cc8-911e-7660dca717bf">
    <Id>101010101010</Id>
  </RandomNode>
  <Item Reference="bf139890-2f7c-4784-8041-68aa5fe7beb1" Provider-Id="101010101010" />
  <Item Reference="5fb8bea0-c79a-4a26-a532-4df59543bc5c" Provider-Id="101010101010" />
  <Item Reference="4f01116a-06f8-4af3-9f4a-87c658eb8008" Provider-Id="101010101010" />
</RootConfig>
```

Currently, I've the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


  <xsl:template match="*[@Type='SomeUniqueType']">
    <Item>
      <xsl:call-template name="provided-reference">
        <xsl:with-param name="reference" select="@Value"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="provided-reference">
    <xsl:param name="reference"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Reference">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($reference, ';')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Provider-Id">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($reference, ';')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I can't find how to do a lookup of the value I got from the `substring-before`, and then get the value of the `Id` attribute.

Any idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to use a key for this, especially if there are many different `RandomNode` elements that you want to use for the lookup. Also, no need for named templates or parameters.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

The template match for `Item` can of course be changed to `match="*[@Type='SomeUniqueType']"` if that's really necessary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="ref-id-to-id" match="RandomNode" use="@RefId"/>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="Value">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Value, ';')"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Provider-Id">
              <xsl:value-of select="key('ref-id-to-id',substring-before(@Value,';'))/Id"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootConfig>
   <RandomNode RefId="519263a7-e01e-4cc8-911e-7660dca717bf">
      <Id>101010101010</Id>
   </RandomNode>
   <Item Value="bf139890-2f7c-4784-8041-68aa5fe7beb1" Provider-Id="101010101010"/>
   <Item Value="5fb8bea0-c79a-4a26-a532-4df59543bc5c" Provider-Id="101010101010"/>
   <Item Value="4f01116a-06f8-4af3-9f4a-87c658eb8008" Provider-Id="101010101010"/>
</RootConfig>
```

By the way, for your next question: A more sensible test case would have contained `Item` elements with references to *different* providers, with distinct IDs.

Comment: I didn't know the `xsl:key` reference. After some research, it looks like obvious that I should have tried with this, since it fits my needs perfectly, thank you! Yeah, I made a lot of shortcuts regarding my real example in the hope the question would be more readable and shorter.

Comment: I ended by using: `<Item Reference="{substring-after(@Value, ';')}" Provider-Id="{key('ref-id-to-id',substring-before(@Value,';'))/Id}"/>` work like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since I did any XSLT, but isn't it?

```
<xsl:value-of select="//RandomNode[@RefId = substring-before($reference, ';')]" />
```

I guess that if you're trying to do it where $reference is not in scope, then you'll have a scoping problem where . points at the context of the square brackets. In that case, you'd have to do:

```
<xsl:variable name="this" value="." />
<xsl:value-of select="//RandomNode[@RefId = substring-before($this/@Value, ';')]" />
```

Assuming that your context would be an Item node.